# PHP, putting a looping variable from a foreach loop into a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this loop:

```
$dir = 'url/dir/dir/'; 
$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg'); 
foreach ($images_array as $image) {
     $image = str_replace($dir, '', $image);   
}
```

I  just want to save the $image variables into a new array. How is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP output of foreach loop into a new array.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531902/php-output-of-foreach-loop-into-a-new-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dir = 'url/dir/dir/'; 
$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg'); 

$images = array();

foreach ($images_array as $image) {
     $images[] = str_replace($dir, '', $image);   
}

var_dump($images);
```